# Vagrant complains "A VirtualBox machine with the name 'homestead-7' already exists"

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, vagrant

Whenever I try to run this command `vagrant up` I am facing following error:

```
VirtualBox machine with the name 'homestead-7' already exists.
Please use another name or delete the machine with the existing name, and try again.
```

What I did, to begin with, I configured everything perfectly, means my Vagrant was working fine. I setup everything in `C: drive` with following directory structures.

```
C:/rec (contains my development Laravel code)
C:/recordings/Homestead (contains homestead files)
```

at that time my `Yaml` configuration was like this
**`.homestead/Homestead.yaml`**

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub    
keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
folders:
    - map: C:\rec
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
```

Until above mentioned state, everything was working fine. But I decided to change `Homestead` folder to my document folder, I did this in `my document`

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
```

This created `Homestead` directory in my documents like this `C:\Users\SweetHome\Homestead`.

I open the command line for this directory and run this command `./init.bat` I created the required files in `.homestead` directory. But after all this, when I run `vagrant up` command in newly created `Homestead` directory, it gives me error

```
VirtualBox machine with the name 'homestead-7' already exists.
Please use another name or delete the machine with the existing name, and try again.
```

If I run `vagrant up` in previous/old directory `C:/recordings/Homestead` everything get working properly. But in new `Homestead` I am facing error.

Guide me on how I can get rid of older `Homestead` and should start working in new `Homestead`. I also tried to remove older `Homestead` directories and run `vagrant up` but same error

Here are some details:

```
$ vagrant box list
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 1.1.0)

$ vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.9.1


$ vagrant global-status
id       name        provider   state    directory
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
5d103ba  homestead-7 virtualbox poweroff C:/Users/SweetHome/Homestead

The above shows information about all known Vagrant environments
on this machine. This data is cached and may not be completely
up-to-date. To interact with any of the machines, you can go to
that directory and run Vagrant, or you can use the ID directly
with Vagrant commands from any directory. For example:
"vagrant destroy 1a2b3c4d"
```

Answer (score 15):

The *Vagrantfile* script of Homestead attempts (by calling *scripts/homestead.rb* script) to create a machine with a default name of 'homestead-7'. That's why it fails, if a box with that name already exists.

You have 2 ways to solve this:

1. Open Oracle VirtualBox and rename the existing machine (through its settings) from 'homestead-7' to any other name, and then run the `vagrant up` command again.
2. Put a line of `name: SomeOtherName` (replace 'SomeOtherName' with what you want) in the *Homestead.yaml* file of the new machine, and the script will use that name instead of 'homestead-7' (it's not documented, but a look inside *scripts/homestead.rb* shows that it first checks for a user-defined name and uses it, otherwise, it uses the name 'homestead-7' by default: `config.vm.define settings["name"] ||= "homestead-7"`)

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Works perfectly.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't accepted but it is definitely the piece of info I was looking for

Answer (score -1):

Just delete the machine with the existing name:  'homestead-7' 
In the program VM.

```
$ vagrant halt
```

or

```
$ vagrant destroy
```

and then

```
$ vagrant up
```

You can also destroy directly in the Virtual Box program 'homestead-7' (or the one you use for the VM) and recreate it following the steps you did before.

Comment: please edit your answer and provide more information